# Marmalade Juice - convert .xcworkspace to Android

Tags: ios, marmalade

I m new in `Marmalade Juice` and I follow the very first tutorial about, How to convert an `iOS` application to an `Android` application.

I have some apps on `AppStore` and all of them uses `CocoaPods` which we all know, wrap the  project with workspace.

How can I convert `.cxworkspace` with `Marmalade Juice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current release (in Marmalade SDK 7.3.1 at time of writing), Juice only supports conversion of individual Xcode projects, not workspaces.

You *could* try converting each project in your workspace independently to create a Marmalade MKB project for each, then modify each of these into a Marmalade subproject and create a master "workspace" Marmalade project that includes each subproject. Then use the Marmalade MKB tool to generate a single Xcode project for your Juice build that includes everything in your workspace.

This isn't something I've tried, so I suspect it will take a bit of doing and research into the Marmalade MKB system to determine how to achieve it.

A good place to look for and ask Marmalade Juice questions is here - https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/topics/juice.html - more direct than Stack Overflow.

Information on the Marmalade project files and tool is here: http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Marmalade+project+files